# Is possible to protect scope (web api) and authenticate client (web app mvc) in same project?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

Good morning,
I need to have in same project both web api and web app mvc.
Web api has to be protected via bearer token and web app mvc has to be authenticated via identity server.
Is it possible protecting a scope and a client in same project?

I think I have to do something like this in startup

```
//this to protect scope api1
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.Audience = "api1";
    });

//this to authenticate mvc client
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{                
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
    options.ClientId = "mvc-implicit";
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("api1");    
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;    
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };                
});
```

Now, I have to call my Api1 using client_credential with an external client.
But it returns me at login page.

Is it possible to do what I want? 
Protected WebApi and Authenticated MVC client in same project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Client and Api working together in IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726956/mvc-client-and-api-working-together-in-identityserver4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Now, I have to call my Api1 using client_credential with an external client. But it returns me at login page.

That seems you misunderstand the scenario . Your MVC application is client also is a resource application which protected by Identity Server (in `Config.cs`):

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
    };
 }
```

I assume you have api controller in your MVC application :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/Values
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

And you have config to protect the api actions by using `AddJwtBearer` :

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.Audience = "api1";
});
```

That means any request to access the `Get` action should have an authentication bearer header with access token append , the access token is issued by your Identity Server(endpoint is `http://localhost:5000/`) and the audience is `api1` .

Now your another client could use client credential flow to acquire access token to access your web application :

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5000");
if (disco.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
    return;
}

// request token
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    Scope = "api1"
});
```

And call your protected actions :

```
var apiClient = new HttpClient();
apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:64146/api/values");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
}
```

So it won't redirect to login page , since client credential in fact is sending HTTP POST request to get access token with app's credential . There is no login page in this scenario .

Comment: I think that the problem is in my startup where I have the config to protect api `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")` and the config to authenticate client `.AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect()`

Comment: However my mvc app is both client (protected by IdentityServer) and also a resource app (protected by IdentityServer). For this when I call a controller about mvc client I need to authenticate behalf a user (enter credentials). Instead when I call an ApiController of resource app I just need to retrieve the access token (authentication behalf client and not user). How can I have to configure correctly my **startup.cs**?

Comment: @MiniDev1 Your client config is correct ,  to access your api , you need to config the schema to just bearer authentication `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` , so that it knows current action is protected by `bearer` authentication .

Comment: see also : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2698

Comment: Thanks so much. I solve with `[Route("[controller]")] [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` in my Api1 (resource app)

Comment: @MiniDev1 ,please consider accept reply as answer which may help others who meet same problem :)